# Как соединить меню к основному контенту

Tags: html, php, css

Здравствуйте, в виду того что только осваиваю язык HTML CSS PHP возник такой вопрос. 
Есть проект, вот код страницы:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Фан страничка GTA V в КГУ</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="PES 2013" width="350px"/></a>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <div class="menu_head">
            <span>Меню:</span>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><a title="Главная" href="index.html">Главная</a></li>
            <li><a title="История игры" href="history.html">История игры</a></li>
            <li><a title="Персонажи" href="pers.html">Персонажи</a></li>
            <li><a title="заголовок" href="ваша ссылка">Пункт меню 4</a></li>
            <li><a title="заголовок" href="ваша ссылка">Пункт меню 5</a></li>
            <li><a title="заголовок" href="ваша ссылка">Пункт меню 6</a></li>
            <li><a title="Опрос" href="opros.html">Опрос</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    <center><img src="images/gta5.jpg"/></center>
    <h1>GTA 5 это криминальная история о трех героях, покоряющих Сан-Андреас</h1>
<p>Grand Theft Auto 5 еще до выхода доказала, что игры – это такой же элемент современной культуры, как кино, телевидение и литература. По всей Европе и США висят растяжки, рекламирующие пятую часть гангстерского сериала. В эфире BBC, Fox News и даже российских телеканалов «Дождь» и «Россия 24» появились сюжеты, в которых эксперты долго и нудно рассказывали о том, почему Grand Theft Auto 5 – это самое настоящее событие, причем такого же масштаба, как выход на широкие экраны «Аватара» или новой части «Гарри Поттера».</p>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">&copy; Разуваев Павел</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Таких страниц у меня получается очень много, и хотелось бы меню, которое слева, навигационное вынести в отдельный файл, чтобы при добавлении новых пунктов не пришлось залезать в каждый HTML документ и редактировать там и потом лезть в следующий. 
Скажите как такое реализовать? В дальнейшем хочу тоже самое проделать с Шапкой и подвалом.

Comment: http://www.php.su/functions/?include

Comment: @soledar10 правильно подсказал, но если у вас есть PHP, иначе, если на чистом HTML сайт сделан, то [http://htmlbook.ru/html/type/frame][1]


  [1]: http://htmlbook.ru/html/type/frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конструкция включений include

Допустим у Вас есть страница index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Название страницы</title>
  <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--[if IE]>
   <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="container">

   <header>
      <h1>Я самый большой и важный тест</h1>
   </header>

   <nav>
      <p><a href="">Пункт1</a></p>
      <p><a href="">Пункт2</a></p>
      <p><a href="">Пункт3</a></p>
   </nav>

   <article>
    <h2>Опрос общественного мнения показал</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>что пароход изобретен: Петром I, А. Эйнштейном и А. Поповым;</li>
      <li>Диего Веласкес писал свои полотна в стиле: империализма, кубизма 
         и империосионизма;</li>
      <li>Фаросский маяк находится в Фаросе;</li>
      <li>конфуцианство возникло в: Италии, Корее и Франции;</li>
      <li>богами торговли и воровства в Древней Греции были: Марс, Меркурий 
          и Дионис;</li>
      <li>Франция – это город;</li>
      <li>богами загробного мира в Египте были: Аид, Анубис и Ассирис;</li>
      <li>столица Золотой Орды — Монголия;</li>
      <li>главные противники Александра Македонского: татаро-монголы, Дедал 
          и Цезарь;</li>
      <li>священными птицами — символами Афин были: ворона и орел;</li>
      <li>в Древней Греции морями повелевали боги: Плутон, Нептун и Тритон.</li>
    </ul> 
   </article>

   <footer>Copyright</footer>

  </div> 
 </body>
</html>
```

теперь смотрим header - будет одинаков для всех страниц

значит создаем файл с расширением php - header.php

по аналогии делаем для nav - nav.php or menu.php

```
                   footer - footer.php
```

теперь наш файл index.php будет иметь следующий вид

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Название страницы</title>
  <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--[if IE]>
   <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="container">

   <?php include("header.php"); ?>

   <?php include("menu.php"); ?>

   <article>
    <h2>Опрос общественного мнения показал</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>что пароход изобретен: Петром I, А. Эйнштейном и А. Поповым;</li>
      <li>Диего Веласкес писал свои полотна в стиле: империализма, кубизма 
         и империосионизма;</li>
      <li>Фаросский маяк находится в Фаросе;</li>
      <li>конфуцианство возникло в: Италии, Корее и Франции;</li>
      <li>богами торговли и воровства в Древней Греции были: Марс, Меркурий 
          и Дионис;</li>
      <li>Франция – это город;</li>
      <li>богами загробного мира в Египте были: Аид, Анубис и Ассирис;</li>
      <li>столица Золотой Орды — Монголия;</li>
      <li>главные противники Александра Македонского: татаро-монголы, Дедал 
          и Цезарь;</li>
      <li>священными птицами — символами Афин были: ворона и орел;</li>
      <li>в Древней Греции морями повелевали боги: Плутон, Нептун и Тритон.</li>
    </ul> 
   </article>

   <?php include("footer.php"); ?>

  </div> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Теперь, если нужно изменить шапку, меню или футер - изменяете в одном месте - изменяется на всем сайте.

Comment: А не могли бы вы подробнее сказать каким образом применить данную конструкцию?

Comment: А вообще конечно лучше вместо таких вставок использовать шаблоны